# Why is property 'id' in jsonResponse undefined in Codecademy React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm in the final stages of the Jammming project working with Spotify API, trying to save a user playlist (and getting practice asking for help here... thank you!). The problem code:
Spotify.savePlaylist

```
let accessToken;
const clientID = 'XXXXX';
const redirectURI = 'http://localhost:3000/';

const Spotify = {
    
    search(term) {
        const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
        return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`,
            { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } 
        }).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(jsonResponse => {
            if (!jsonResponse.tracks) {
                return [];
            }
            return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => ({
                    id: track.id,
                    name: track.name,
                    artist: track.artists[0].name,
                    album: track.album.name,
                    uri: track.uri
            }));
        });
    },

    savePlaylist(name, trackUris) {
        if (!name || !trackUris.length) {
            return;
        };
        let accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
        let headers = {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`};
        let userID;
        return fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', {headers: headers}
        ).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            response.json();
        }).then(jsonResponse => {
            userID = jsonResponse.id;
            return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/user/${userID}/playlists`,
            {
                headers: headers,
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({name: name})
            }).then(response => response.json()
            ).then(jsonResponse => {
                const playlistID = jsonResponse.id;
                return fetch(`/v1/users/${userID}/playlists/${playlistID}/tracks`,
                {
                    headers: headers,
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({uris: trackUris})
                })
            })
        })
    },

    getAccessToken() {
        if (accessToken) {
            return accessToken;
        }

        const accessTokenMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
        const expiresInMatch = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);

        if (accessTokenMatch && expiresInMatch) {
            accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1];
            const expiresIn = Number(expiresInMatch[1]);
            window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
            window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
            return accessToken;
        } else {
            const accessURL = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientID}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}`;
            window.location = accessURL;
        }
    }
};

export default Spotify;
```

The error I get is: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.  My app is using [implicit grant flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow) and by logging the response from the API I see this:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
locked: true
__proto__: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me"
__proto__: Response
```

I'm pretty stumped and wondering if this response, which doesn't seem like user access is being granted, is me on the right track to debugging this. Can folks school me a bit? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error says is that you trying read `id` from undefined, not that `id` is undefined, so the variable you trying read id from, `jsonResponse` is undefined.

Take close look at your `savePlaylist` function, and notice that you dont return json from the response, what makes `jsonResponse` in next `then` in the chain undefined and that is where you are trying to read `id` from undefined variable. Add `return` before `response.json()` and try again.

The reason why you dont see any `id` property when `console.log` `response` is because the id is within the body of that response and the body is not shown there by `console.log`, `console.log(response.json())` would probably yeld the parsed json response you're looking for and `id` would be within that object.